# How to get field names and records from a return object

Tags: python, database, datahandler

I m trying to get field names and record values from a return database object. I have a datahandler.py file for query exection. when i hit a datahandler method(say for eg. GetEmployeeinfo(id)) from one of source file it return a object. I want to know how to get the field names and record vlues from the object which is returned by GetEmployeeinfo(id).

MyCode looks like this:

Employee.py

```
 class EmployeeForm(BrowserView)

 def getEmployee(self):
    handler=self.MyDBHandler()
    emp_info=handler.GetEmployeeinfo(id=1) // this return the object from a 
                                              GetEmployeeinfo(id)
    return emp_info
```

dbhandler.py

```
  class MyDBhandler():

  def GetEmployeeinfo(id,dic=0)
    //some select statement query goes here 
     return []
    // it return the object instance like "<My.Product.dbhandler.xxxx>"
```

I want to know how to get the field names and records from the return object in Employee.py file to return it to the render page.

thanks in advance.

Comment: read the docs for that employeeinfo to see what attribute that class may have

Comment: actually the method GetEmployeeinfo() returns employeeinfo(tablename) instance

Comment: yes see the attributes of the table class(namely a wrapper class I guess) from the docs

Comment: Have you tried to access like this - **empName = emp_info['emp_name']**, if i understand your question correctly.

Comment: @zhangxaochen: can you pls give exaample how to return the fieldnames and records from the return object(which i mentioned above)

Comment: @Krishnraj Rana: No, your wrong. That object is not a substitutable object. SO yours idea will not work for my case

Comment: Have a look at this method in python - [getattr(object, fieldname)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

Comment: i think the dbhandler return a list-like object.To put this another way, dbhandler return a record list.

Comment: @neo_blackcap: neo i dont have rights to change the dbhandler return statement. So i only need to know how to get the keys() and values() from the return object.

Comment: i mean if you want to get record, every element in the return list is record object. And if you want to get the field name, maybe the dir(element form return list-like object) will work.Of course, dir() will get a lot of uesless information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the docs for that class as long as you have one.
2. `print help(My.Product.dbhandler.xxxx)` to see the help info on that class, or use `print dir(My.Product.dbhandler.xxxx)` to see the attributes and methods of that class.
3. If you have some IDE(e.g. eclipse with pyDev) or enhanced shell/editor(e.g. iPython) with **auto-completion**, just type `My.Product.dbhandler.xxxx.<TAB>` to see the code completion.